# How to ensure full path in Windows batch FOR loop

Tags: windows, batch

I've created a generic batch (or Windows Command) file that lets me loop through the contents of a directory and call a command for each item.

```
IF a%1==a ( set _DIR="%CD%") ELSE ( set _DIR="%~1")
IF a%2==a ( set _COMMAND=rem) ELSE ( set _COMMAND=%2)
IF a%3==a ( set _FILTER=*.*) ELSE ( set _FILTER=%3)
set _OPTS=%4

FOR /F "delims=" %%f IN ('dir %_DIR%\%_FILTER% %_OPTS% /b') DO (
%_COMMAND% "%%f"
)
```

But, I'm trying to determine how to ensure that I call `%_COMMAND%` on the correct file.

I've tried pre-pending the directory variable onto the front, like `%_COMMAND% %_DIR%\"%%f"`, but this leaves a quotation mark in the parameter I pass.  For example, if I call my batch file `exec_dir.bat`, and call it with the following `echo_test.bat`, I see that all of the files have a quotation mark when `echo_test.bat` runs.

```
echo %~dpn1.mp4
```

That batch script produces:

```
> exec_dir.bat "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test Folder" echo_test.bat *.txt
C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test Folder\"Test File.txt
C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test Folder\"Test2.txt
```

My thought is that it has something to do with the `\` as an escape character, but I can't seem to work around it.

Comment: i am not sure if any of these ideas will help but you know %1  %~f1 makes it full. Also, dir /b  doesn't seem to give the full path, but dir /b /s does, though i guess you don't want /s.  another thought is you can cut bits off of an environment variable  e.g. echo abc  , then echo %a:~1,2%  not sure if that's useful to you

Answer (score 0):

```
setlocal
if "%~1"=="" (set dir=.) else (set dir="%~1")
if "%~2"=="" (set command=echo) else (set command=%~2)
if "%~3"=="" (set mask=*) else (set mask=%~3)
for /r %dir% %%f in (%mask%) do %command% %%~dpnxf
```

Or simply:

```
C:\>for /r . %f in (*) do @echo %~dpnxf
```

Comment: I didn't use the `FOR /R %_DIR% %%f IN (%_FILTER%) DO` syntax because I wanted support for recursion.